# Can't load MSMQ COM Object on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, msmq, com, activex

My VBScript tries to load MSMQ COM Object

```
Set MSMQQueueInfo = CreateObject("MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo")
```

I enabled Messaging DCOM Proxy

[image]

Script can't load COM object:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I am not running MSMQ on this server, I still had to install the messaging server to load the COM object:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the machine you are creating the queue on.

[Using Message Queuing over DCOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703266(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The error I'm getting happens before there's a chance to worry about machine name. I couldn't create the COM object.

Comment: The object is created using the machine name, not before you specify the machine name. 
Set qinfo = CreateObject("MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo", "MyServer.MyDomain.com")

Comment: As I posted in the question, I'm creating without the name `CreateObject("MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo")`

Comment: My assumption (as I can't test it at the moment) is that the proxy needs to know the queue manager to talk to for object creation. If you don't specify then the QM would have to be local.